# Unix Shell Script to search directory for all media files (audio and video)

Tags: linux

I need help i doing two things.

a) Search the current directory for all media files (i.e. songs and videos) and build a
list of available files to be played.
b) Display an appropriate message if no media files were found and give the user the
option to close the program.

Thanks much

Comment: Use the `file` command in line 13.

Answer (score 1):

Python will do the job perfectly and easily. It is a very good script language, and easy to leaner, you can try to use it. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
files = os.listdir('.')
available_files = []
for f in files:
    if f.endswith('.mp3') or f.endswith('.mkv'):
        available_files.append(f)
if not available_files:
    print 'there is no media file in current dir'
```

Comment: @RoundRobin I've upvoted this, even though it's not a shell script, because doing shell scripts that manipulate lists of filenames *well* is hard and makes for really ugly code. e.g. linux filenames can contain newlines, and such filenames will break dgarant's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your files have extensions:

```
file_pattern="*.mp3|*.mp4|*.flv"
file_count=`ls 2>/dev/null | egrep $file_pattern | wc -l`
if [ $file_count -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "No files found"
else
   echo `ls | egrep $file_pattern`
fi
```

You can modify `file_pattern` to include any other file extensions you want to search for.